# DBFlow for Android synchronous save

Tags: android, database

I have recently started working on an Android project which includes a [DBFlow database](https://github.com/Raizlabs/DBFlow/). I need to make a synchronous save, or at least give it the highest priority so the save will happen ASAP.

From the [documentation on GitHub](https://github.com/Raizlabs/DBFlow/blob/master/usage/Transactions.md) it seems like this would be possible but I am not able to understand how exactly do you implement this and am getting errors, like when trying to write this line:

`ProcessModelInfo<SomeModel> processModelInfo = ProcessModelInfo<SomeModel>.withModels(models)                                                                         .result(resultReceiver)
.info(myInfo);`

This is the first time I am working with databases.